# Visual Studio Lightswitch 2013 HTML... how to calculate and display?

Tags: c#, javascript, lightswitch-2013

It's a rather simple area really, I've got my lightswitch application hooked up to my sql server, and what I want to do is add say 3 values together from this table using a computed field... I know the c# code side here will work as this is what I'm good at, however now I've got this value in my table, how do I display it on the screen view in javascript?

It doesn't show up in the table list to be dragged and dropped onto the screen.

Comment: My first thought would be to add a custom control and then load and display the computed field in the render method. I'll play with that and see if it works.

Comment: Ok, it seems to be a bit more involved than I originally thought. This blog post shows a way to make it happen. http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/185/Computed-Properties-With-the-LightSwitch-HTML-Client.aspx